# Why alter user lock, still can query?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle database 21c Express edition in Windows x64.
With system user, I run

```sql
alter user `bichvan` account lock
```

With system user

[image]

but, in Oracle SQL Developer, session of user `bichvan`, I still can query.

[image]

Why alter user lock, still can query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/axdbi/locking-and-unlocking-user-accounts.html#GUID-6A8D4A59-6DB2-4662-BA4C-05B914D31B4F) says:

> To temporarily deny access to the database for a particular user account, you can lock the user account. **If the user then attempts to connect, then the database displays an error message and does not allow the connection**.

It means that lock won't affect currently logged users. But, if you disconnect and then try to connect, you won't be allowed to do that.

Comment: You should add reference link to your answer.